# Scrapy Item pipelines not enabling

Tags: python, django, scrapy, pycharm

I am trying to set up a Scrapy spider inside Django app, that reads info from a page and posts it in Django's SQLite database using DjangoItems.
Right now it seems that scraper itself is working, however, it is not adding anything to database. My guess is that it happens because of scrapy not enabling any item pipelines. Here is the log:

```
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 6e614667b3cf5a1a
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-10-05 15:23:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-10-05 15:23:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-10-05 15:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.barbora.lv/produkti/biezpiena-sierins-karums-vanilas-45-g> (referer: None)
2019-10-05 15:23:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.barbora.lv/produkti/biezpiena-sierins-karums-vanilas-45-g>
{'product_title': ['Biezpiena sieriņš KĀRUMS vaniļas 45g']}
2019-10-05 15:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-10-05 15:23:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 259,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 15402,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.418066,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 5, 12, 23, 8, 417204),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 5, 12, 23, 7, 999138)}
2019-10-05 15:23:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As I  can see, the scraper returns expected value as "{'product_title': ['Biezpiena sieriņš KĀRUMS vaniļas 45g']}", but it seems like it is not passed into pipeline because no pipelines are loaded.

I have spent several hours looking at different tutorials and trying to fix the issue, but had no luck so far. Is there anything else I might have forgotten regarding setting up the scraper? Maybe it has something to do with file structure in the project.

Here are relevant files.

items.py

```
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
from product_scraper.models import Scrapelog


class ScrapelogItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Scrapelog
```

pipelines.py

```
class ProductInfoPipeline(object):
  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      item.save()
      yield item
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scraper.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scraper.pipelines.ProductInfoPipeline': 300,
}
```

spider product_info.py:

```
import scrapy
from product_scraper.scraper.scraper.items import ScrapelogItem

class ProductInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'product_info'
    allowed_domains = ['www.barbora.lv']
    start_urls = ['https://www.barbora.lv/produkti/biezpiena-sierins-karums-vanilas-45-g']

    def parse(self, response):

        item = ScrapelogItem()
        item['product_title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
        return ScrapelogItem(product_title=item["product_title"])
```

Project file structure:

[image: project_structure]

Comment: You are asking why the item pipeline is not enabled. Is that the only setting that is not picked up? Have you checked if other settings are picked up? Is the working dir at run time the one where the scrapy.cfg file is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further tinkering and research I found out that my settings file was not properly configured (however, it was only part of the problem). I added these lines to code based on other resources (they link Django project settings with scrapers settings):

```
import sys

import django

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), ".."))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'broccoli.settings'
django.setup()
```

After that, the spider did not run, but this time it at least gave an error message about not finding the Django settings module. I don't remember the exact syntax but it was something like that: *"broccoli.settings MODULE NOT FOUND"*

After some experiments I found out that moving scraper directory "scraper" from inside the app "Product_Scraper" to same level with other apps helped deal with this issue and everything worked.